# dynamic array to two functions

Tags: c++

I created a program that will use a dynamic array by using pointer to find the max and min from a set for integer that the user will enter.

I actually can get the output of max, but not for min; I found out my dynamic array will result to 0 after the calculation from the function of max, and made my min became the value of the assigned value of min.

I have no idea why it is like this - I tried many ways, but these were useless so can someone explain why, and provide a solution if possible or give me some hint for how to get through the solution?

---

Thank your replies

seem like my code had confused to your

Sorry

the program intent to get the maximum and minimum digits from an amount of integers

From I what I tried to say is after calculation from the function of max, the data from the dynamic array would become 0, and when program go through the function of min, it would not gonna run because the data from dynamic array had been set to 0

So actually what I wanna ask is is there anyway to make the data from the dynamic array not become to 0 after the function of max?

Sorry for my poor English

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void max(int*, int);
void min(int*, int);

int main()
{
   int *ptr;
   int i;
   int size;

   cout << "how many integer: ";
   cin >> size;

   ptr = new int[size];

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      cout << "integer#" << i << ": ";
      cin >> *ptr + i;
   }

   max(ptr, size);
   min(ptr, size);

   delete [] ptr;

   return;
}

void max(int* ptr, int size)
{
   int i;
   int j;
   int max = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      while (*ptr + i != 0)
      {
         j = *ptr + i % 10;

         if (j > max)
         {
            max = j;
         }

         *ptr + i /= 10;
      }
   }

   cout << max << endl;
}

void min(int* ptr, int size)
{
   int i;
   int j;
   int min= 0;

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      while (*ptr + i != 0)
      {
         j = *ptr + i % 10;

         if (j < min)
         {
            min= j;
         }

         *ptr + i /= 10;
      }
   }

   cout << min<< endl;
}
```

Comment: please indent your code with spaces.

Comment: Why are you doing those things with the number `10`, and why do you use pointer arithmetic instead of array indexing?

Comment: If you have a "set" then consider using [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Comment: In the future, you should really refrain from using variables with the same name as the function they are in, e.g. the function `max` with the local variable `max`. It makes the code more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: This is program is to find the max and min from a set of integers input from the user, so i used pointer to point the input from the user to the function, then the function will calculate all the stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what compiler you have used, but your code is not even compiling without some modifications on my GCC 4.6.

1. All `*ptr + i` becomes `*(ptr + i)`.
2. `return;` at the end of `main()` becomes `return 0;`.

The other issue is that in function `void min(int* ptr, int size)`, you are initializing `min` as `0`. What you should really do is `int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();` so that `min` has the highest possible integer value. Don't forget the `#include <limits>`.

Here is a code that finds the ***minimum digit*** and ***maximum digit*** without modifying the original array (a good practice),

```
void max(int* ptr, int size) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int temp;
    int max = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp = *(ptr + i);
        while (temp != 0) {
            j = temp % 10;
            if (j > max)
                max = j;
            temp /= 10;
        }
    }

    cout << max << endl;
}

void min(int* ptr, int size) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int temp;
    int min = 10;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        temp = *(ptr + i);
        while (temp != 0) {
            j = temp % 10;
            if (j < min)
                min = j;
            temp /= 10;
        }
    }

    cout << min<< endl;
}
```

Comment: I am using visual C++ 2010 express

Comment: thank for organized my code, and the program intent to get the maximum and minimum digits from amount of integers

Comment: @RexRau I have updated my code to reflect this. It won't modify the array. If you are satisfied, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: oh, thank you for the code, so it is about the pointer, and from your updated code, the variable of temp is to make copy of the pointer , so it would not change my data from my array right? thank you :D

Comment: @RexRau It is ___not copying the pointer___. It makes a ___copy of the data___, but the rest of what you said is correct, :). Copying the pointer won't help here, since the copy will also point to the same location and will eventually modify the data.

Answer (score 0):

One issue here is precedence for operators.

You are trying to use `*ptr + i` to access the i'th element.
Dereferencing(`*`) has the highest precedence and evaluates before the addition.

`*(ptr +i)` or the more common `ptr[i]` should do the trick.